# How to organize/structure Cypress tests with reusable functions across multiple spec/test files

Tags: typescript, automation, automated-tests, components, cypress

We just started using Cypress to test our component library in Storybook. We write our integration/functional tests in Typescript. Unit tests are written elsewhere.

I'm struggling with the organization of the tests, I come from the Selenium world where I used to use POM approach. Currently, I have one spec file named [Componenent].test.ts (we don't use *spec* as we noticed it's usually reserved for unit tests).

Currently, each test file contains a bunch of functions and constants declared at the top that are used by the tests. If we take a `Grid` as an example, these functions are mainly to retrieve a row, a tooltip, edit a cell, etc. so that we centralize the selectors and don't duplicate code.

Soon we want to add accessibility tests and visual tests for these components. Therefore, I have a few questions.

1. I could write all these tests within the same test file as the functional tests. I'm not a fan of this approach, because it’s messy and if I want to run just the accessibility tests or visual tests  then I can’t isolate them with `“–spec“` to only run them
2. I want to create separate test files for visual and accessibility tests that I would drop in a different folder so in the end I would have the following folders: integration, accessibility, visual
   I would also need to append something to the test file name to know what type of test it is. My main question is how do I reuse the functions and commands within all these files? My 3 component test files will need to use the same constants, functions, etc...

I don’t think Typescript supports hierarchical inheritance and I keep hearing I should not use POM. I also noticed I could write them in the functional test file and export them and import them in the two other files but not sure if it’s the right approach. I’m new to this as you can see.

Suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better organisation, we could:

1. Put custom commands into each separate commands files (e.g. based on functionality).
2. In the declaration `index.d.ts` file, we can separate the general `interface` to extends other `interface` (which are more specific). For example:

```
// index.d.ts
interface AuthenticationChainable {
  login(): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>;
  logout(): void;
}

interface InputChainable {
  input(): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>;
  toggle(): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>;
}

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable extends AuthenticationChainable, InputChainable {
      // general commands
      navigateTo(): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>;
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

```
// commands.ts
Cypress.Commands.add('navigateTo', () => {
  ...
});
```

```
// authentication-commands.ts
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
  ...
});
```

```
// input-commands.ts
Cypress.Commands.add('input', () => {
  ...
});
```

3. For re-usable functions which are not custom commands, you can put them under a `util` or `helper` file.

```
const isAsset = (asset: Asset): boolean => {
  ...
};

export const assetUtils = {
  isAsset,
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer that's a nice way of organizing things

Answer (score 1):

Cypress custom commands might solve point two you have. https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax

We use them for commands that are used across the testing suite. TypeScript provides a good way to add documentation with examples for each command as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes we use already custom commands but as you mentioned, we use them for things that are used across all our components. 
In this case I was looking for a way to centralize some functions that are used by some components but not all.

For now I created a helper file with these functions that I export. My test files import these functions. 
Not sure if there's a better approach. To your point I do wonder if I should use custom commands even for this case and create multiple command files. My worry is that the commands files will grow so much.

Comment: That's one thing Cypress cautions against. They recommend keeping the functions as close to the test as possible, if not inside the test file itself. To avoid crowding the commands file.

Comment: @onimougwo I don't think there's a functional downside to putting commands in a commands file that apply to some components but not others, but for better organization, you might consider breaking out your commands into separate files and then import them into commands/index.js. For "utility" functions that we do not use as commands, we also created "helper" files. We made a directory called util/ that contains an index.js that imports all our helper files.

Comment: Thank you @majorobot that's what I ended up doing !